# Find value of index in Map Array using string key

Tags: c++, dictionary, maps

In an array `map<string, int> bannd` such that each key (of type string) holds a number value, like this

```
+++++++++++++++
key   |  value
+++++++++++++++
red   |   0
blue  |   1
orange|   3
```

etc...

What is the optimal way to return the value of an index using the key?

I already tried using find like this

```
band1 = band.find("a");
```

where a is the key value in the map, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) Mind you, that assumes we are talking `std::map`. [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns where in the `map` you can find the item you were looking for, or the end iterator if it wasn't found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` returns an *iterator* pointing to the found key-value `pair` (if any). You have to *dereference* that iterator to get the actual mapped value:

```
int band1;
auto it = band.find("a");
if (it != band.end())
  band1 = it->second;
else
  /* not found ... */;
```

Note that `*it` just gives us the `std::pair` containing the key and mapped value together. To access the mapped value itself we use `it->second`.

Alternatively, if you know that the key is in the `map`, you can use `at` to get the mapped value for that key:

```
int band1 = band.at("a");
```

`at` will throw an `out_of_range` exception if the element is not found.

Finally, if you want to access the value with key `"a"` and you want to automatically add that key to the `map` if it is not already there, you can use the subscript operator `[]`:

```
int band1 = band["a"]; //warning: inserts {a, 0} into the map if not found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function, which takes `std::map` and `std::vector` of key as argument. And it will return the corresponding values in `std::vector`

```
vector<int> valueReturn(map<string,int> data, vector<string> key) {
    vector<int> value;
    for(const auto& it: key) {
        auto search = data.find(it);
        if(search != data.end()) {
            value.push_back(data[it]);
            std::cout << "Found " << search->first << " " << search->second << '\n';
        }
        else {
            value.push_back(-1); // Inserting -1 for not found value, You can insert some other values too. Which is not used as value
            std::cout << "Not found\n";
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the logic of your answer. OP just wants an `int`

Comment: @user4581301 : Since multiple values can not be returned from a function. Hence i am returning a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it say OP wants multiple values. `std::map` does not support multiple keys. You would want a `std::multimap` for that.

Comment: @user4581301 : I think you misunderstood me. OP wants value (band1,2,3,4) for the input a,b,c,d right ?. I am taking map and key as input and returning the corresponding values.

Comment: OK. I see where you are coming from and think you are over-complicating things and risking a lot of unnecessary copying.On the plus side, the extra copies prevent running into the same problem Brian did. `operator[]` will only insert new elements into the copy of the map if unknown keys are used.

Comment: @user4581301 : Yes, Now i have edited my answer and handling this situation too.

Answer (score -1):

```
int band1 = band["a"];
int band2 = band["b"];
int band3 = band["c"];
int band4 = band["d"];
```

Comment: This has the side effect of adding an item to the `map` and returning the new item's default value, 0 in this case, if the item is not in the `map`. May not be what OP wants.